# Calculate difference with last year [Python] [Pandas] [ dataFrame.diff()]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns: year, month and sale.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'year': [2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023], 
 'month': [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
 'sale': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]})
```

I need calculate difference sale value between a moth with last year.

I use df.diff() in pandas:

```
df['last_year'] = df['value'].diff(periods=df['month'])
```

When I run this code, I receive the error notion:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How can I calculate difference sale values with last year?

Comment: Just use `df['sale'].diff()`, or per year if you have several times each month `df.groupby('month')['sale'].diff()`